# Is Bekenstein-Hawking black hole entropy the maximum bound of the entropy of a black hole?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy, hawking-radiation

Is the entropy $S_{BH}=\frac{c^3 A}{4Gh}$, where A is the surface area of the event horizon of a black hole, the "real" entropy of the black hole or a maximum bound of that "real" entropy?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound#Examples

Comment: Thank you but I have already read these, and it is still confusing on what exactly this formula describes

Comment: Oh, ok. *"the Bekenstein–Hawking boundary entropy of three-dimensional black holes exactly saturates the bound"* So a black hole has the maximum possible entropy, which is equal to ¼ of its event horizon's area in square Planck lengths.

Comment: So what i understand is that a 3-dim black hole has the maximum possible entropy all the time, it does not get reduced, because its area of the event horizon cannot reduce, but there is a possibility when studying black holes in higher dimensions to find ones with lower entropy than 1/4 of its event horizon. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about black holes in higher dimensions. In 3 dimensions, a BH has maximum entropy all the time. So if you increase its mass (by dropping stuff into it) you also increase its entropy. A BH can reduce its entropy by Hawking radiation, but that process increases the entropy of the rest of the universe.

Comment: Note that the Hawking radiation temperature of a stellar mass BH is around a billionth of a degree above absolute zero, and the really big ones are even colder. BHs won't be able to lose mass by Hawking radiation until the background temperature of space is colder than that, in the very far distant future (around $10^{50}$ years, IIRC).